# How to assign icon/image to a tbbuttoninfo?

Tags: visual-c++

How can I assign a new image for my TBBUTTONINFO button? help me..

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    TBBUTTONINFO tbButtonInfo;
    ::ZeroMemory(&tbButtonInfo, sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO));
    tbButtonInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO);
    tbButtonInfo.dwMask = TBIF_IMAGE;
    tbToolbar.GetButtonInfo(nId, &tbButtonInfo);
    tbButtonInfo.iImage = I_IMAGENONE;
    tbToolbar.SetButtonInfo(nId, &tbButtonInfo);
```

For detailed information, please check the MSDN documentation for TBBUTTONINFO.